# call on dynamic added html elements a jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, listener

my have some trouble to call a JavaScript/jQuery 1.9.1 method on dynamic added html-elements.

### Here is my JS-code:

```
$(".download").live("click", function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(buttonId);
});
```

### My dynamic HTML code:

```
  var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i <daten.length; i++) {
       html += "<input id='" + daten[i].pfad + "' class='download' type='image' width='25px' height='25px' src='/download.png'/>";
    }
  $("#table").append(html);
```

I get no error message, but the method is besides not calling, what is here not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .on instead

```
$(document).on("click",".download",function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(buttonId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `on()`, as `live()` was deprecated and removed in newer versions of jQuery:

```
$('#table').on('click', '.download', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6tuv/)

works for me ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
  $(document).on("click",".download",function() {

   //put your code here

  });
```